# How to enable interactive grid cell validation in Oracle Apex Master-Detail page?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have created a Master-Detail page in my Oracle APEX application. Basically i have a list of rows from one table and I can add values to it though a form. That works correctly, validations also work (every column from Master form can be accessed by adding ":" in front and that works in this case). I also have an option to edit click pencil icon in front of every row which lets me to update current row and also displays the Detail part of that row. Detail part is a list of values from another table that is connected to the first one using foreign key (Master-Detail: one to many). It is automatically displayed as interactive grid, so when editing my Master table value I can also add new rows to Detail table, but the validations don't work for Detail table. I tried accessing it's columns the same way as before, but it just doesn't work (tried to add PL/SQL expression validation:

```
:column >= 0
```

but that didn't work. How can I enable the validation for interactive grid, because I've looked into some resources about it, but they just show the first way, that doesn't work for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a validation on an Interactive Grid you need to set the attribute "Editable Region" for the validation to your interactive grid. That works ok for me. I tried with a Master Detail on Dept (Master) and Emp (Detail) with a validation on detail of :SAL > 1000

[image]

Comment: For some reason this doesn't work for me. When trying to add new values, validations are ignored.

Comment: I fixed the issue (partly) by adding a check constraint on the database table. Thank you for trying to help me.